# Dynamic Formik Form Data population throwing controlled input error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik, dynamic-forms

I have created two dynamic forms A and B in Formik each having pre-populated data from Atype Btype keys from the JSON and can be viewed with radio buttons at the top. The validations and initialization of first  form works well for the initial load of page. However when I toggle the view to second form, it gets initialized with data of first form and validations fail as well.Attaching the sandbox url for proper undesratnding.Please help. Atching sandbox url https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-voice-9i93v?file=/index.js

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `enableReinitialize` inside formik field. Othewise when formik component runs initialValue render only on first time. This is why its is not updating your value:

```
<Formik
        onSubmit={async (values) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }}
        initialValues={
          Atype ? getInitialValues(data, "A") : getInitialValues(data, "B")
        }
        enableReinitialize
        ...rest all things here
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-dust-3k9xp?file=/index.js

Comment: Wow!!...Thanks a lot...where is this thing written in docs?

Comment: Yes its in doc: https://formik.org/docs/api/withFormik#enablereinitialize-boolean